# Arch Linux can't set wlo1 to "UP"

Tags: networking, arch-linux, networkmanager

I recently installed Arch Linux on my Asus X403F VivoBook laptop, through an ethernet connection. But now, I want to connect it to a wireless connection. When I started network manager, via `nmtui` , it didn't prompt any networks. I ran `nmcli`, and it told me my interface (wlo1) was unavailble. Here is exactly what it outputted:

```
wlo1: unavailable
        "Realtek RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac"
        wifi (rtw_8822be), 66:CA:92:88:5E:CC, hw, mtu 1500
```

I ran `ip link`, and this happened:

```
2: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 66:ca:92:88:5e:cc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff permaddr dc:f5:05:37:5a:59
    altname wlp2s0
```

after that, I ran `ip link set wlo1 up`, but it gave me this:

```
RTNETLINK answers: Operation already in progress
```

,and now I do not know what to do.

Thanks in advance.